# .net calendar control dimensions under vista

Tags: .net, calendar, size, width, dimensions

I'm developing a desktop application in Visual Studio 2008, and I've made the *delightful* discovery that evidently under Vista, the Calendar control is 45 pixels wider than the same control in XP. Naturally, this ruins the layout of my from, and I don't have space to give. If I tinker with the dimension attributes of the calendar in Vista (using VS2008 running on Vista), as soon as the field loses focus, it snaps back to 227 pixels. Is there a way to resize this bugger or to force it to use the style of calendar that was in XP? It seems really obnoxious to change the fundamental size of a control and break applications that would have otherwise run on both operating systems.

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed this too.. it's a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Disable Visual styles but this would make your app look really weird. You can do this by removing this line from your Main method:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```